# Rule-based symbols activatable/deactivatable also in QGIS server and QWC2

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, qwc2

I am new to QGIS Server but I have a running installation QGIS Server with a standalone QWC2 webapp.

In QGIS Desktop I have created with several layers a layers-group-hierarchy where data features are rendered for each layer with rule-based symbols definitions (colors).

In QGIS Desktop those rule-based symobols are shown within the layers-group-hierarchy and each symbol "item/entry" is activatable / deactivatable individually. This is very helpful for selective visual data analysis.

When this QGIS Desktop project file is published in
QGIS Server this ability of individual activatable / deactivatable symbols are "gone" and a single legend is rendered.

Is there any way, that this ability of QGIS Desktop can be maintained/configured also in QGIS Server or what would be a feasible workaround (beside creating for each symbol its own duplicate layer)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any workaround except creating layer duplicate for each symbol.

As you are using QWC2, you can also deploy QWC services and qwc-config-generator to help split categorized layers in a group layer with each symbol as a layer in it. You can start to deploy all the services with [qwc-docker](https://github.com/qwc-services/qwc-docker).

See this [script](https://github.com/qwc-services/qwc-config-generator/blob/master/config_generator/categorize_groups_script.py) and [documentation](https://qwc-services.github.io/configuration/ThemesConfiguration/#split-categorized-layers)

Comment: Many thanks. The mentioned scrip ["categorize_groups_script.py"](https://github.com/qwc-services/qwc-config-generator/blob/master/config_generator/categorize_groups_script.py) pointed me to correct direction. I adpoted it to run as standalone pyhton3 script.